# PDFBox returns isEncrypted true even if i can open file

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am using PDFBox to determine pdf file is password protected or not.
this is my code:

```
boolean isProtected = pdfDocument.isEncrypted();
```

My file properties is in sceenshot.
Here i am getting `isProtected= true` even i can open it without password.

Note: this file has Document Open password : No and permission password : Yes.

[image: click here to view file]

Comment: @Tilman in his answer correctly described the situation you are in. But is that what you wanted? Your "question" misses an actual question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your PDF has an empty user password and a non empty owner password. And yes, it is encrypted. This is being done to prevent people to do certain things, e.g. content copying.

It isn't a real security; it is the responsibility of the viewer software to take care that the "forbidden" operations aren't allowed.

You can find a longer (and a bit amusing) explanation [here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/Adobe/Gallery/anon21jul01-pdf-encryption.txt).

To see the document access permissions, use `PDDocument.getCurrentAccessPermission()`.

In 2.0.*, a user will be able to view a file if this call succeeds:

```
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(file);
```

If a `InvalidPasswordException` is thrown, then it means a non empty password is required.

Comment: Thanks for replay, I want true if user can view pdf without password and false if user can not open pdf file without password.Can u plz help me here. In my above scenario user can open/view pdf file without password then it should return true.

Comment: In 2.0.* if you can open the file with PDDocument.load(File), then it means a user can view it.

Comment: Hello,I am ready to migrate pdfbox to 2.0.2. What is equivalent method of pDFTextStripper.resetEngine() in pdfbox 2.0.2

Comment: @NitinVavdiya there isn't (its private). You don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this answer because elsewhere on Stack Overflow and the web you might see the suggested way to check for a password protected PDF in PDFBox is to use `PDDocument#isEncrypted()`.  The problem we found with this is that certain PDFs which did not prompt for a password were still being flagged as encrypted.  See the accepted answer for one explanation of why this is happening, but in any case we used the followed pattern as a workaround:

```
boolean isPDFReadable(byte[] fileContent) {
    PDDocument doc = null;
    try {
        doc = PDDocument.load(fileContent);
        doc.getPages();  // perhaps not necessary
        return true;
    }
    catch (InvalidPasswordException invalidPasswordException) {
        LOGGER.error("Unable to read password protected PDF.", invalidPasswordException);
    }
    catch (IOException io) {
        LOGGER.error("An error occurred while reading a PDF attachment during account submission.", io);
    }
    finally {
        if (!Objects.isNull(doc)) {
            try {
                doc.close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (IOException io) {
                LOGGER.error("An error occurred while closing a PDF attachment ", io);
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

If the call to `PDDocument#getPages()` succeeds, then it also should mean that opening the PDF via double click or browser, without a password, should be possible.

Comment: According to the accepted answer (and also to a quick&dirty code review) already the successful `PDDocument.load(fileContent)` operation suffices, no need to retrieve the pages.

Comment: @mkl I added a comment to your point.  In any case, the accepted answer is basically lacking in implementation, which my answer provides.